# WP-CLI Cannot Connect to Database due to Vagrant

Tags: wp-cli

I am running the most recent version of WP-CLI on my mac. I do all WordPress development within Vagrant, but would like to run WP-CLI commands in the host machine. I have a domain alias from "dev.mysite.com" to the IP of my server so it can be accessed through my web browser through an HTTP request.

When trying to run a WP-CLI command, I get an "Error Establishing a Databse Connection" error mesage because it is trying to connect via "localhost" when it really should be "dev.mystie.com" or the Vagrant VM's IP Address. Is there any way I can access my site through WP-CLI without having to SSH into the guest?

Answer (score 5):

Since the issue is probably DB configuration you could try adjusting it conditionally in `wp-config.php`:

```
if ( defined( 'WP_CLI' ) ) {
    define( 'DB_HOST', 'example.com' );
}
else {
    define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried updating wp-config.php to change the database host?

Alternatively why not use command + t in terminal to open a new tab then vagrant ssh in there and use that for WP-CLI?

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at [wp-cli-ssh](https://github.com/x-team/wp-cli-ssh)

> Seamlessly run WP-CLI commands on a remote server via SSH

I know you don't want to SSH to the guest, but this at least, supposedly, removes the need to do it manually.

I figured out how to set it up.

Follow [these steps](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/wiki/Community-Packages#setting-up-the-package-index)

```
mkdir -p ~/.wp-cli
cd ~/.wp-cli
touch composer.json
php composer.phar init --stability dev --no-interaction
php composer.phar config bin-dir bin
php composer.phar config vendor-dir vendor
php composer.phar config repositories.wp-cli composer 'http://wp-cli.org/package-index/'
```

Create or edit `config.yml`in the same folder and add:

```
require:
  - vendor/autoload.php
```

Install the package with:
`php composer.phar require x-team/wp-cli-ssh=dev-master`

Then just running `wp` should display a list of available subcommands, and you should have `ssh` added to that list.

Then we configure the plugin in `wp-cli.local.yml` or `wp-cli.yml`:

```
ssh:
  vagrant:
    # The %pseudotty% placeholder gets replaced with -t or -T depending on whether you're piping output
    # The %cmd% placeholder is replaced with the originally-invoked WP-CLI command
    cmd: vagrant ssh-config > /tmp/vagrant_ssh_config && ssh -q %pseudotty% -F /tmp/vagrant_ssh_config default %cmd%
    # Passed to WP-CLI on the remote server via --url
    url: local-www.yourawesomewebsite.com
    # We cd to this path on the remote server before running WP-CLI
    path: /your/vvv/path/
```

And run it all with `wp ssh plugin status --host=vagrant`

... It's just to bad that this plugin assumes Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants. Since my vagrant environment hosts a lot of sites the Vagrantfile isn't in the WordPress directory, breaking the whole thing...

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to utilize [@aliases](https://wp-cli.org/commands/cli/alias/) to trigger [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org) commands on the   [`basic-wordpress-vagrant`](https://github.com/ideasonpurpose/basic-wordpress-vagrant) box from my host machine. Maybe this could help you.

> ~/.wp-cli/config.yml

```
@basic:
    ssh: basic.dev/var/www/wordpress/
```

> ~/.ssh/config

```
Host basic.dev
    HostName basic.dev
    User vagrant
    IdentityFile ~/sites/basic.dev/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
```

> $ wp @basic theme list